# Is it possible to import data into MATLAB from a SAS database?

Tags: matlab, sas

I'm working on an automation project and was wondering if it's possible to establish a connection between MATLAB and a SAS database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For instance, you can use Matlab's **sasread** function to read from SAS

```
sasfile = 'C:\sasreaddemo.sas7bdat';
xlsfile = 'C:\SAS-Matlab Converter.xls';
[numeric,text,raw] = sasread(sasfile,xlsfile)
```

Example files are available:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15835-import-data-from-sas